# Android Media Player crash when changing datasource

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I`m using a service to play the music in the background. the user have a list of songs that he can listen online or downloading them and listen offline.
the problem appears when the user is in offline mode. if he downloads a song he can play it with no problems, but if he skip to the next one(not downloaded) and there is not internet, it does not work as expected and this is not a problem. the problem appears when the user skip to previous one which is downloaded, this time its not playing

```
private void initMediaPlayer() {
        int sura_number = activeSuraModel.getSura_number();
        String formatted_sura_number = String.format("%03d", sura_number);  //001

        String path = activeSuraModel.getReciter_server() + "/" + formatted_sura_number + ".mp3";


        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        //Set up MediaPlayer event listeners
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        //Reset so that the MediaPlayer is not pointing to another data source
        mediaPlayer.reset();

        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {

            String downloadedFilePath = downloadedFiles.getDownloadedFilePath(downloaded_files_map, activeSuraModel, reciterName);    

            if (downloadedFilePath == null) {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path); // get online
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(downloadedFilePath);// get from storage
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("pat", "error  " + e.getMessage());
            stopSelf();
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }
```

---

```
 private void playMedia() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
```

---

```
 private void skipToNext() {

        if (suraIndex == suraModels.size() - 1) {
            //if last in playlist
            suraIndex = 0;
            activeSuraModel = suraModels.get(suraIndex);
        } else {
            //get next in playlist
            activeSuraModel = suraModels.get(++suraIndex);
        }

        //Update stored index
        new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).storeAudioIndex(suraIndex);

        stopMedia();
        //reset mediaPlayer
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        initMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void skipToPrevious() {

        if (suraIndex == 0) {
            //if first in playlist
            //set index to the last of audioList
            suraIndex = suraModels.size() - 1;
            activeSuraModel = suraModels.get(suraIndex);
        } else {
            //get previous in playlist
            activeSuraModel = suraModels.get(--suraIndex);
        }

        //Update stored index
        new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext()).storeAudioIndex(suraIndex);

        stopMedia();
        //reset mediaPlayer
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        initMediaPlayer();
    }
```

---

```
 @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        if (isRepeat) {
            mp.start();
        } else if (isShuffle) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int random_number = random.nextInt(suraModels.size());
            activeSuraModel = suraModels.get(random_number);
            initMediaPlayer();
        } else {// play next song
            skipToNext();
        }


    }
```

---

```
private void stopMedia() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) return;
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have stacktrace, log? And can you put you `stopMedia()` method?

Comment: please check the updates. and i implemented onError method and it gives me a strange code>> int what: 1, int extra: (strange big number)